# Возможно сделать плавное появление слайдов slick slide?

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

Подключен slick slide. Слайды - текст. Вертикальный режим. Требуется сделать плавное появление этих слайдов. Подскажите как?

Comment: Покажите что есть на текущий момент

Comment: Требуется как тут http://atmt.ru
Сейчас у меня они не плавно выезжают.

Comment: посмотрите в [документации](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). Вообще по-умолчанию плавно выезжать должны

Comment: "сейчас они у меня" - приложите ваш код.